# Mouse emulation on Raspberry Pi 4 does not work

Tags: python, linux, windows, emulation, hid

For a personal project I am currently trying to make my Raspberry Pi 4 emulate both a keyboard as well as a mouse. The keyboard emulation works really well and convincing, but I keep getting problems when it comes to emulating the mouse. 
I've configured my Pi as an HID device with the following code being executed at boot:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir -p pihid
cd pihid
echo 0x1d6b > idVendor # Linux Foundation
echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # v1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB # USB2
mkdir -p strings/0x409
echo "fedcba9876543210" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "test" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "PiHID" > strings/0x409/product
mkdir -p configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo "Config 1: ECM network" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration
echo 250 > configs/c.1/MaxPower

# Add functions here
mkdir -p functions/hid.usb0
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/protocol
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/subclass
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb0/report_length
echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x06\\xa1\\x01\\x05\\x07\\x19\\xe0\\x29\\xe7\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x75\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x08\\x81\\x03\\x95\\x05\\x75\\x01\\x05\\x08\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x05\\x91\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x03\\x91\\x03\\x95\\x06\\x75\\x08\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x65\\x05\\x07\\x19\\x00\\x29\\x65\\x81\\x00\\xc0 > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc
ln -s functions/hid.usb0 configs/c.1/

mkdir -p functions/hid.usb1
echo 2 > functions/hid.usb1/protocol
echo 2 > functions/hid.usb1/subclass
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb1/report_length
echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x02\\xA1\\x01\\x09\\x01\\xA1\\x00\\x05\\x09\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x03\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x95\\x03\\x75\\x01\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x05\\x81\\x03\\x05\\x01\\x09\\x30\\x09\\x31\\x15\\x81\\x25\\x7F\\x75\\x08\\x95\\x02\\x81\\x06\\xC0\\xC0 > functions/hid.usb1/report_desc
ln -s functions/hid.usb1 configs/c.1/
# End functions

ls /sys/class/udc > UDC
```

After boot there are two files in `/dev`, called "hidg0" and "hidg1", which I should be able to write to. Writing keyboard commands to "hidg0" works completely fine with this python script:

```
NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(6)+chr(7)+chr(8)+chr(9)+chr(10)+chr(11))
write_report(NULL_CHAR*8)
```

When I am in editor, "cdefgh" will appear.

This is my script I use to write to "hidg1":

```
NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

def ms_write(report):
    with open("/dev/hidg1", "rb+") as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

ms_write(NULL_CHAR+chr(100)+NULL_CHAR*6)
ms_write(NULL_CHAR*8)
```

But after executing, instead of moving the mouse 100 units, nothing happens and the program finishes.
What am I doing wrong concerning the mouse emulation or the communication with the Windows HID Drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I think the mouse needs 3 bytes instead of 8. Also, try wb+ instead of rb+

```
NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

def ms_write(report):
    with open("/dev/hidg1", "wb+") as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

ms_write(NULL_CHAR+chr(100)+NULL_CHAR)

ms_write(NULL_CHAR*3)
```