# raspberry pi 4 - trying to emulate mouse and keyboard - BrokenPipeError: [Errno 108] Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I have a Pi4 running Bookworm with Kernel 6.1.21 and I'm tring to emulate the keyboard and mouse.
I have a boot script running that looks like this one: [Mouse emulation on Raspberry Pi 4 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68274446/mouse-emulation-on-raspberry-pi-4-does-not-work)

I followed the basics from this link: [enter link description here](https://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383) to initialize some kernel bits.

I try to run these examples from a python file:

```
NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

#keyboard
def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(6)+chr(7)+chr(8)+chr(9)+chr(10)+chr(11))
write_report(NULL_CHAR*8)

#mouse
def ms_write(report):
    with open("/dev/hidg1", "wb+") as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())

ms_write(NULL_CHAR+chr(100)+NULL_CHAR)
ms_write(NULL_CHAR*3)
```

and the error I get is : BrokenPipeError: [Errno 108] Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown

From searching around, I can see that working examples use older installations with other kernels, so this might be the issue.

Or the setup is somehow wrong as most examples are for the Pi Zero connecting on to another device, which is not what I'm doing.

Anyone out there that has this working with Bookworm or any poointers what the issue could be ?

My initialize bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initializes the device by adding necessary kernel modules.

set -e

reboot_required=0

# Make sure we use the dwc2 USB driver.
# This driver is capable of handling OTG, consequently
# allowing this device to act as USB slave.

if ! grep "dtoverlay=dwc2" /boot/config.txt; then
  echo "dtoverlay=dwc2" >> /boot/config.txt
  reboot_required=1
fi

# Enable the corresponding kernel module.

if ! grep "dwc2" /etc/modules; then
  echo "dwc2" >> /etc/modules
  reboot_required=1
fi

if [ $reboot_required -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Please reboot the device for the initialization to take effect"
else
  echo "Everything set up"
fi
```

And my setup Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

modprobe libcomposite

cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir -p pihid
cd pihid

echo 0x1d6b > idVendor # Linux Foundation
echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # v1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB # USB2

mkdir -p strings/0x409
echo "fedcba9876543210" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "test" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "PiHID" > strings/0x409/product
mkdir -p configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo "Config 1: ECM network" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration
echo 250 > configs/c.1/MaxPower

# Add functions here
mkdir -p functions/hid.usb0
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/protocol
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/subclass
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb0/report_length
echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x06\\xa1\\x01\\x05\\x07\\x19\\xe0\\x29\\xe7\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x75\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x08\\x81\\x03\\x95\\x05\\x75\\x01\\x05\\x08\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x05\\x91\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x03\\x91\\x03\\x95\\x06\\x75\\x08\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x65\\x05\\x07\\x19\\x00\\x29\\x65\\x81\\x00\\xc0 > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc
ln -s functions/hid.usb0 configs/c.1/

mkdir -p functions/hid.usb1
echo 2 > functions/hid.usb1/protocol
echo 2 > functions/hid.usb1/subclass
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb1/report_length
echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x02\\xA1\\x01\\x09\\x01\\xA1\\x00\\x05\\x09\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x03\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x95\\x03\\x75\\x01\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x05\\x81\\x03\\x05\\x01\\x09\\x30\\x09\\x31\\x15\\x81\\x25\\x7F\\x75\\x08\\x95\\x02\\x81\\x06\\xC0\\xC0 > functions/hid.usb1/report_desc
ln -s functions/hid.usb1 configs/c.1/
# End functions

ls /sys/class/udc > UDC

#chmod 777 /dev/hidg0
#chmod 777 /dev/hidg1
#
```

And /etc/rc.local:

```
#mouse emulator config
sudo /home/martinval/projects/hid/mouse_keyb.sh

sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/hidg0
sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/hidg1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup code is nearly identical to mine apart from the mouse and keyboard descriptors. I can see you are using hidg0 for keyboard & hidg1 for mouse.

I wasn't having much luck getting other people's descriptors (from articles) to work, so in the end I obtained a physical Logitec mouse & Logitech keyboard plugged them into my Mac and then used this project https://github.com/todbot/mac-hid-dump to get authoritative descriptors:

keyboard:

```
\\x05\\x01\\x09\\x06\\xa1\\x01\\x05\\x07\\x19\\xe0\\x29\\xe7\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x75\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x08\\x81\\x01\\x95\\x05\\x75\\x01\\x05\\x08\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x05\\x91\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x03\\x91\\x01\\x95\\x06\\x75\\x08\\x15\\x00\\x26\\xff\\x00\\x05\\x07\\x19\\x00\\x2a\\xff\\x00\\x81\\x00\\xc0
```

mouse:

```
\\x05\\x01\\x09\\x02\\xa1\\x01\\x09\\x01\\xa1\\x00\\x05\\x09\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x03\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x75\\x01\\x81\\x02\\x05\\x01\\x09\\x30\\x09\\x31\\x09\\x38\\x15\\x81\\x25\\x7f\\x75\\x08\\x95\\x03\\x81\\x06\\xc0\\xc0
```

so maybe try these?

BTW this works fine for my RaspberryPi 400 but unfortunately I am seeing the same error as you when I try the same SD card on my custom CM4 based board (which is what led me to find your question) but this may well be a hardware problem on my board.

At a glance it looks like your test script is fine, but I'll post these here anyway:

'helloworld' python test script for keyboard:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time

def send_key_event(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'wb') as keyboard_hid:
        keyboard_hid.write(bytearray(report))

def press_and_release_key(keycode):
    send_key_event([0x00, 0x00, keycode, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])
    time.sleep(0.1)
    send_key_event([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])

keycodes = [
   0x0b,
   0x08,
   0x0f,
   0x0f,
   0x12,
   0x2c,
   0x1a,
   0x12,
   0x15,
   0x0f,
   0x07
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for keycode in keycodes:
        press_and_release_key(keycode)
```

mouse right click python test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time

def send_mouse_event(buttons, x, y):
    with open('/dev/hidg1', 'wb') as mouse_hid:
        # Prepare report: buttons, x, y, wheel
        report = [buttons, x, y, 0]
        # Write report to HID device
        mouse_hid.write(bytearray(report))

def mouse_left_click():
    print("mouse_left_click")
    # Press left button
    send_mouse_event(0x01, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # Release left button
    send_mouse_event(0x00, 0, 0)

def mouse_middle_click():
    print("mouse_middle_click")
    # Press middle button
    send_mouse_event(0x04, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # Release left button
    send_mouse_event(0x00, 0, 0)

def mouse_right_click():
    print("mouse_right_click")
    # Press right button
    send_mouse_event(0x02, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # Release right
    send_mouse_event(0x00, 0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mouse_right_click()
```